# SQL merge result of two columns

Tags: sql

i have a table like so -

firstName - lastName - dob - region - authority

and this is the query im using

```
 SELECT firstName, lastName, region from whatever
```

is it possible to merge the firsName and lastName like so within the result, I need to keep the firstName and lastName separate within the actual database but merge them within the result like so -

firstname lastname - region

Comment: In Oracle Database you would use `||` operator, in SQL Server you would use `+` operator. What database are you using? – it is not clear from your question or tags.

Comment: `||` is actually even ANSI SQL!

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev: the `||` operator is not specific to Oracle. This is what the has been defined in the SQL standard nearly 30 years ago.

Comment: BTW, you're trying to merge two columns, not rows.

Comment: Microsoft SQL management studio 2005, CONCAT didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would be like:

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT firstname || ' ' || lastname as name, region from whatever
```

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname ,' ', lastname) as name, region from whatever
```

**MSSQL:**

```
SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname as name , region from whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName,' ',lastName) as Name, region from whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
 SELECT firstName || ' ' || lastName as name, region from whatever;
```